# Cut and paste at the end of existing node

Tags: xml, xslt

Simple question for you today :). I am trying to cut data from a node and paste it at the end of data in another node.

So it should look like this:

```
<x>
   <a>1234</a>
   <b>5678</b>
</x>
```

desired output

```
<x>
   <a>12345678</a>
</x>
```

My current testing xslt is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:param name="ename">Test</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="evalue">Test1234</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="removeElementsNamed" select="'Test'"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="input">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test="not(c)">
                <xsl:element name="{$ename}"><xsl:value-of select="$evalue"/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>                
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:if test="not(name() = $removeElementsNamed)">
        <xsl:call-template name="input"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I know that something should be in `<xsl:copy>` tags but i dont really know what. Tried few things none worked. Help appreciated thank you

**EDIT**: i just realized that my problem is slightly more complex and i should now show why.

My xml file has the following structure

```
 <root>
   <payload>01234</payload>
   <metadata>
      <metadata-element>
          <key>key</key>
          <value>value</value>
      </metadata-element>
   </metadata>
   <metadata>
       <metadata-element>
           <key>foo</key>
           <value>5678</value>
       </metadata-element>
   </metadata>
</root>
```

desired output

```
<root>
   <payload>012345678</payload>
   <metadata>
      <metadata-element>
          <key>key</key>
          <value>value</value>
      </metadata-element>
   </metadata>
</root>
```

Comment: This could probably be a *lot* simpler. Why don't you post a more realistic sample of your input XML.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It would help knowing if the `<metadata>` elements should be picked by their order or by some value.

Comment: @user3016153 by value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input structure you have chosen to show us, this stylesheet will do.

**EDIT**: updated stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="payload">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::metadata/metadata-element[key='foo']/value"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="metadata[metadata-element/key='key']">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="metadata-element|key|value">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="metadata[metadata-element/key='foo']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yields the following output:
**EDIT**: Updated output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <payload>012345678</payload>
 <metadata>
  <metadata-element>
     <key>key</key>
     <value>value</value>
  </metadata-element>
 </metadata>
</root>
```

> I know that something should be in  tags but i dont really
>   know what.

Note that xsl:copy copies the node in context to the output tree. If your template matches `a` elements, this instruction copies `a` to the output tree. Any XLST code you write inside of `xsl:copy` will be placed inside of the copied element.

Im am well aware that your input XML is in fact very different, but you did not enclose it. Therefore, my post simply answers what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you, however i realized that my problem is slightly more complex i have edited my questions accordingly

Comment: Alright, I have edited my stylesheet and output. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This stylesheet assumes input XML exactly as you have shown it. If you want to process other input structures, please show them to us, and say clearly what the selection criteria are and so on...

Comment: The input xml structure is as shown, the whole problem is far far more complex and to long for stackoverflow + its not really relevant. I am still running tests and changing order of few things maybe i have a mistake somewhere

Comment: well there is a problem, the metadata is still where it was but payload dissapears

Comment: I am working with Saxon 9.1 took your input as shown, the stylesheet is exactly as I have shown it. The payload does **not** disappear.

Comment: Yes i can see in my logs that there is an issue in my code not your transformation method :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/payload">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., following-sibling::metadata[2]/metadata-element/value)" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::metadata[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

EDIT:

Since you say they should be selected by value (I presume it's by the value of the `<key>` element):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/payload">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., following-sibling::metadata[metadata-element/key='foo'][1]/metadata-element/value)" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::metadata[metadata-element/key='key'][1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your xslt throws illegalArgumentexception :) on <root> tag

Comment: @MaciejCygan I have tested it with no less than three different processors (libxslt, Xalan and Saxon), as well as with the online service at http://xslfiddle.net/ and it works fine on all four of them.

Comment: This solution works fine and throws no errors. @Maciej: We've helped you an awful lot already, consider the possibility that some of your other code / your processor / platform / handling is wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right :) i do appreciate your help Mathias and user and both solutions work, its in my code that error happens after i do transoformation and therefore it disappears